# Does parenting object A to object B mean A is the parent or is it the other way around?

Tags: parent

super basic question here. I'm looking at online guides and tutorials and the phrase "parent object A to object B" pops up a lot. I'm under the impression that this means that object A will become the parent of object B, but I've seen some guides that make it seen as if it were the other way around.

In general, when someone says "parent object A to object B" which object would becomes the parent?

Comment: I think it's an expression that may ultimately differ from person to person. However, I personally would say that this means that object B is intended to be the Parent.

Answer (score 0):

When parenting an object. The object most recently selected will become the parent. And the other objects will be childs. For example, if you selected object "B" first, and then object "A" last, object "A" would be the parent, and object "B" would be the child.